# Slide Animation start when layout is opened

Tags: android, animation

How can I do an `animation` in my `activity` without any trigger?
I have an `ImageView` which I want to `animate` to a sliding `animation` but the `animation` is **NOT** from `Left` to `Right` or `Top` to `Bottom` vice versa.
but instead from the `CENTER` of the screen to the `BOTTOM LEFT`which is look like this.

[image: Slanted Sliding Animation]

Comment: What already have you tried?

Comment: These may help you to know about animations [Animate all the things. Transitions in Android](https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50)   and  [lgvalle/Material-Animations](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations)

Comment: I cant find any sliding animation.. only `TransitionDrawables` so im curious how to animate in android.. i know its different from `CSS3`

Comment: @FarshidABZ thank you for the information it helped a lot now i have to read more :)

Comment: @FarshidABZ using those references it comes with a button how to trigger those animation without button i tried removing `onClickListeners` but its not working

Comment: @GelliEspiritu do you want to run an activity with an animation?